# When using UIScrollView, how can I fade the left and right edges if content is outside the visible bounds?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, calayer, mask, cagradientlayer

Let's say I have a horizontally scrollable `UIScrollView` with various types of content. It could be images, UIViews etc. I would like to fade transparent the left and right edges if the content is outside those edges.

I have tried using the following but it doesn't appear to work correctly.

```
class CustomScrollView: UIScrollView {
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        print("layoutSubviews")
        
        if layer.mask == nil {
            let mask = CAGradientLayer()
            mask.locations = [0.0, 0.2, 0.8, 1.0]
            
            mask.startPoint = CGPoint(x:0, y:0)
            mask.endPoint = CGPoint(x:1, y:0)

            layer.mask = mask
        }
        
        if let mask = layer.mask as? CAGradientLayer {
            
            mask.bounds = self.frame
            let fadedColor = UIColor(white: 1.0, alpha: 0.0).cgColor
            let realColor = UIColor(white: 1.0, alpha: 1.0).cgColor

            var colors = [CGColor]()

            colors = [fadedColor, realColor, realColor, fadedColor]
                        
            mask.colors = colors

            CATransaction.begin()
            CATransaction.setDisableActions(true)
            CATransaction.commit()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close...

You want to set the mask layer's **frame**, not its **bounds**.

Also, you can do all of the gradient layer setup in the `if equals nil` block, instead of on every layout pass:

```
class CustomScrollView: UIScrollView {
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        print("layoutSubviews")
        
        if layer.mask == nil {
            // do all the GradientLayer / Mask setup here
            let mask = CAGradientLayer()
            mask.locations = [0.0, 0.2, 0.8, 1.0]
            mask.startPoint = CGPoint(x:0, y:0)
            mask.endPoint = CGPoint(x:1, y:0)
            
            let fadedColor = UIColor(white: 1.0, alpha: 0.0).cgColor
            let realColor = UIColor(white: 1.0, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
            
            mask.colors = [fadedColor, realColor, realColor, fadedColor]
            
            self.layer.mask = mask
        }
        
        if let mask = layer.mask as? CAGradientLayer {
            CATransaction.begin()
            CATransaction.setDisableActions(true)
            mask.frame = self.bounds
            CATransaction.commit()
        }
    }
    
}
```